# RewriteRule on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

localhost, xampp, win 7
site root folder is `s02`, so all relevant files, including `.htaccess` is under this folder.

links like this work fine:
`http://localhost/news/s02/view.php?art=160915142500&title=blue-sky`

I want the following computed url
`http://localhost/articles/160915142500/blue-sky`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)$ view.php?art=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

result - error 404

**httpd.conf**
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` - uncommented
`AllowOverride All`

**.htaccess (test)** - this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [L,R]
```

**phpinfo();**
`mod_rewrite` is under `Loaded Modules`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule, we are telling apache that incoming uri is not a file or directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)$ /news/s02/view.php?art=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This works only if I place `.htaccess` inside `C:\xampp\htdocs` folder and `view.php` is loaded but without dependecies (images, css, js...). Is there a way to keep `htaccess` inside `C:\xampp\htdocs\news\s02` folder and get `view.php` with all elements ?

Comment: use `<base href>` tag for loading css and js correctly.

Comment: `base href` works, thanks. What about root folder?. If I keep `htaccess` inside `htdocs` it will be working for all my local sites. I need each site to have its own `htaccess`, if any.

Comment: Do this put htaccess in news directory and try my edited rule.

Comment: Do you mean `news/s02`. Site root folder is `s02`. All files, including index.php, view.php... are there.

Comment: Then what is news directory?

Comment: full path is `C:\xampp\htdocs\news\s02`. `so2` means `site02` for me (versus `site01`, for example).

Comment: Actually it's my mistake you have to use the rule in htdocs otherwise your rewrite rule should be like this `http://localhost/news/s02/articles/160915142500/blue-sky` if you use your rule in `s02` directory or else you will get 404 error, there is no other way.

Comment: Abhishek, keeping `htaccess` in `htdocs` is not a standard, I suppose, because of other local sites. What about removing `articles/` part from url? What is usual practice in my case? I just want to have SEO friendly url instead of `view.php?art=..`

Comment: 'I know but then your url must start from `news/s02/` not from `articles/160915142500/blue-sky` if you want to store htaccess in so2 that's what I know or else you will get 404 error or else you must change config in httpd.conf and make so2 as root instead htdocs folder

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Place `.htaccess` file into the root folder i.e. htdocs for xampp (I guess). The `.htaccess` file should be like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)$ news/s02/view.php?art=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Works fine on my system. created the scenario `<root_folder>/news/s02/view.php` and placed `.htaccess` file same as above into the root_folder.

Comment: Try restarting your xampp server

Comment: What is your root folder, pls. Here is mine full path: `C:\xampp\htdocs\news\s02`. `.htaccess` is under `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Comment: I am using wamp server so mine root folder is `C:\wamp\www` and full path for the `view.php` file is `C:\wamp\www\news\s02\view.php`

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `.htaccess` file in your `C:\xampp\htdocs\news\s02\` folder unless necessary.